# Actions-on-Google SDK: respond without registering handlers

Tags: javascript, nodes, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am working on an app for Google Home and Google assistant.

I use express as a web server for the fullfillment. In most cases, I manually check the request to decide what to respond and manually send a JSON as express response.
In some cases, I use the actions-on-google SDK which is set up as the following instead to send the reply.

```
const { DialogflowApp } = require("actions-on-google");
const assistant = new DialogflowApp({
    request: request,
    response: responseToAssistant
});
```

In version 1.11 of actions-on-google SDK, I could also use `assistant.tell('Thanks for talking to me!');` to send a response (instead a manual JSON).

I've now updated to version 2.2. However, in this version it looks like I *have to register the handlers for all intents, to use the actions-on-google SDK to send a response.*

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => { // (registering intent)
  conv.close('Thanks for talking to me!'); 
});
```

However for that, I would have to restructure the whole project. Is it somehow possible to still check the request manually (without registering all intent-handlers) and use the actions-on-google SDK to send a response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a handler that will be called in the event none of the other registered handlers would be triggered. Your code would be something like this:

```
app.fallback(conv => {
  conv.ask("Everything else is handled here!");
});
```

If you want to set the raw JSON in these cases, you should be able to call the `conf.json()` method with the JSON you want to set.

Comment: thanks @Prisoner, this might be the right approach. However, can I also access the express response within the closure to manually send responses?

Comment: Answer updated. (Tho I haven't tested the answer myself - just looked through the documentation and code.)

Comment: thank you, it works! I was looking for exactly that but couldn't find it. You helped me a lot :)